# What happens to canceled requests to a PHP page?

Tags: php

When a long-running PHP file is executing, and the user cancels the page request in their browser midway, is the rest of the script ran on the server?

Comment: AFAIK, they will still complete execution on the server. Why don't you test it out? All you need to do is place some sleep in your PHP file.

Comment: Haha, I was just looking at the PHP sleep function on php.net when you said that.

Comment: I'm with @AlecSmart. If you've ever accidentally sent a massively unoptimized database query via phpmyadmin you know the process can run for a lonnnng time after you've developed blisters clicking the stop button. This may be a result of the MySQL server being involved though and you could get different results from a purely PHP script with no db access.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PHP normally terminates script execution once it realizes that the connection is closed:

> PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an
>   attempt is made to send information to the client. Simply using an
>   echo statement does not guarantee that information is sent, see
>   flush().

You can keep your script running using [ignore_user_abort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php).

Also, there is a default time limit for which scripts are allowed to run.  You may want to override that using [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: Terminating the script execution sounds... insecure. Especially when making MySQL queries.

Comment: Use transactions when appropriate, that's what they are for.  Your script may terminate early regardless... power outage, server crash, etc.

Comment: Excellent point. I'll have to start doing some looking into transactions.

Comment: Using register_shutdown_function() with a connection_aborted() test can allow you to put in special handling for a trapped user abort, letting you clean things up before script execution actually terminates... though it does have some limits. Database transactions should be used to handle rolling back all db activity in an aborted transaction - transactions were invented for precisely this purpose long before PHP or the web ever existed.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this once on a long running process and discovered that the script will continue to run once it has not exceeded the maximum time to execute.

Answer (score 0):

For me (using XAMPP on an older computer), cancelling the web page in the middle of an operation meant to process one million primary records, with a couple of other tables being updated in the process, the MySQL database operations kept going, which tells me that the PHP script kept running on the server.  By "cancelling," I mean clicking the stop button on the tab, but not closing the tab altogether.  BTW: I had established set_time_limit() to 0 to keep the script from timing out before completing in absence of cancelling.